# Why does Fox specify to fix the lever in an upright position, on a Rhythm 34 fork that uses a Through-Axle?

Tags: fork, through-axle, fox

I vaguely remember that "conventional wisdom" states that closed QR levers on MTB forks should point towards the back of the bike (see [Which direction should QR lever point?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/26007/which-direction-should-qr-lever-point) or [What is the proper position for quick-release levers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43113/what-is-the-proper-position-for-quick-release-levers)). However, I just saw that Fox
 specifies something different from the anwers to these questions in the manual of the Rhythm 34 thru-axle fork: "The closed lever position **must** be between 1-20 mm in front of the fork leg.", i.e. like this:

[image: fox manual]

Out of curiosity: Why is this so? Would it be harmful in any way if I ride with the lever pointing backwards instead of upwards?

Source (image and quote): Fox manual https://www.ridefox.com/dl/bike/605-00-136-34-Tuning-Guide-revC.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper position for quick-release levers?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43113/what-is-the-proper-position-for-quick-release-levers)

Comment: Not downvoted but flagged as duplicate content

Comment: @DanK I saw these questions, but the answers specify that the lever should point towards the back of the bike. I'm specifically asking about the contradiction between these answers and the manual of the fork (and have hopefully made that more clear now), and whether it is harmful to follow the answers instead of the manual. Could you kindly explain how this is a duplicate? (Or have I misread the answers to the other questions and they actually are in line with the manual?)

Comment: Could be opinion based: I think that the position is irrelevant per se. But the company promotes this position so that the user can check at once whether the QR is properly tightened. This may be included in the instructions for legal reasons to avoid claims.

Comment: @anderas the accepted answer to the Q linked as duplicate says nearly the same as Fox does. "Quick release angle on the front skewer shall be an upward angle which tightens just aft of the fork " that's for roadies. Doesn't work with the shape of the fork depicted in your Q, hence it's arsy-versy now. You ask why it is different from what you consider the consent for lever alignment. However, such a consent is not established. Flagging as duplicate is a way to express that the assumptions your Q is based upon are not solid with the mechanisms provided.

Comment: See also an answer suggesting this lever position:https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/43117/30402

Comment: @gschenk Thanks! I really thought that there was a universal consent, but re-reading all of the answers, two common opinions seem to exist. So I'll leave it to the community to decide whether this is a duplicate or whether "why does fox specify *exactly* this position?" is interesting enough by itself :)

Comment: On on Fox suspension fork, I don't want to QR lever to be in the way of my rebound adjustment

Comment: @anderas that is an interesting question. Still possible to modify it without breaking context for the present answers?

Comment: @PaulH that's a great point - and its a valid answer to the question so should be an answer, not mixed in with comments.  Would you please put that in an answer ?

Comment: Regarding the posted duplicate - this question is specifically about a through axle with a flippy handle, not a Quick Release that provides clamping forces.   So they're different, and this one is about the Fox recommended angle as well.  VTLO for those reasons.

Comment: @Criggie i'll propose an edit to your answer to include it

Comment: @PaulH why not post it as your own answer?

Comment: @criggie didn't realise it's a TA. Retracted my closer vote. sorry anderas.

Comment: @gschenk it seems like a minor detail that's a better fit in a more comprehensive answer

Comment: @gschenk I'm not sure how to edit the question without at least partially invalidating the current answers, so I'll probably just leave it as-is. Sorry all for the confusion, and thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I'd put a QR lever at an angle close-to a frame tube but absolutely not touching the frame.

The main purpose is to stop the QR lever being opened or loosened by any sort of foreign object.   That may be another rider's wheel/tyre, a stick or road rubbish kicked up and catching wrong, or even a lucky catch on live foliage.

One difference is that's all about QR levers for QR skewers, where one flip of the lever leaves the skewer quite loose and retained just by gravity and lawyer lips.

Your quote is about a through-axle / thru-axle, where flipping the lever generally does not start any sort of disengagement.  Instead you have to unscrew the axle with that lever.  So in theory the lever could be closed or open without issue other than marring your paintwork or possibly catching on grass or maybe spokes (unlikely).

As long as the QR or TA lever isn't being rotated, and was closed to the correct torque, then the lever could be at any angle provided it doesn't rub or catch.

---

One later thought - the recommended distances could be about east of un-doing the lever.  I remember having to use an extra lever on a super-tight QR that was fitted to fork dropouts through a bare hub, ie without a wheel built on the buh.    If OP's TA lever was pointing forward or backward, the rider may be tempted to push on spokes or on the nearest piece of rim.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the manual writing team knew they had to specify a 'safe' QR position so the company would be covered legally. In consultations with the engineering and legal team they decided that in front of the fork leg was the safest position, or at least the position that a company lawyer could defend as the safest position in the case of a lawsuit.

Answer (score 2):

Some QR levers won't close all the way if they are impeded by the frame/fork. My guess is that is the reason for this particular lever.